# How to set up an entirely backpressure driven flux in Java Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a situation where I need multiple workers (let's say 2).
Workers must perform a task consuming upstream events.

The task at hand consumes a list of events and has a constant time independent from the size of the list.

Therefore I wish upstream to deliver a list with all the buffered events **only** when requested to, 1 list at a time.

Sadly most methods implement prefetching.
What happens is that even using 
`limitRate(1, 0)` upstream receives one too many `onRequest(1)`, just to replenish the downstream buffer.

So I struggle to have the buffered list produced just when a worker is available: they are usually produced in advance missing my goal of maximizing the size of the buffered list.

**How can I implement such a setup?**

**Is there a way to disable prefetching altogether?**

Comment: What you describe sounds like a pull based approach, which makes me wonder why you use Reactor in the first place. Maybe you can elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've understood the question correctly. Sample code that shows what you are doing currently would help.

One way to not pull data from the source until an `onRequest` is to `defer` the instantiation of the Flux. So your code would look something like:

```
Flux source = Flux.defer(() -> getFluxForUpstreamSource());
```

Another way to consume from a source using backpressure is used `Flux.generate`. Your code would look something like:

```
Flux source = Flux.generate(
        UpstreamSource::getConnection,
        (connection, sink) -> {
            try {
                sink.next(connection.getNext());
            } catch (UpstreamException e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
            return connection;
        }
);
```